# Проблема с фоном при верстке. Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В общем, сижу туплю. Много чего перепробовал, но верное решение так и не пришло ко мне. Скорее всего все очень просто, но увы и ах.

Как должно быть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу с использованием сетки Bootstrap 4. Не знаю как расположить правильно фон. Он должен быть двухцветный. При этом должен выходить за пределы container бутстрапа. А соответственно все остальное должно быть в контейнере.
Как расположить объекты внутри - я знаю. Проблемы со структурой кода в html для двухцветного фона на одном row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов, идею думаю поймешь:

```css
.wapper {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #37d0e8 50%, #f4a142 0);
}

.col-sm {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wapper">


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of two columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of two columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Про градиент я совершенно забыл :(